# Error displaying a prototype cell and its content

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, null, cell

I'm doing Rob's UDEMY iOS8 Swift course and so far so good.

I use a Tab Bar Controller to separate tabs: Profile, Ask, Browse etc...

In the 'Ask' tab, I input a text and it is successfully uploaded to Parse and I want that text to be displayed in the 'Browse' tab. The Browse tab is a Table View with prototype cell, I added labels there to display username and the text.

My problem is that it doesn't display the text nor the username from Parse. Here is the code:

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class browseViewController: UITableViewController{


var postedQuestion = [String]()
var usernames = [String]()




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var query = PFQuery(className:"Post")

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error != nil {



            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                for object in objects {

                    self.postedQuestion.append(object["postedQuestion"] as! String)

                    self.usernames.append(object["username"] as! String)

                    self.tableView.reloadData()

                }
            }
        } else {

            println(error)
        }
    }


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}



override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return usernames.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 227
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var myCell:cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell") as! cell


    myCell.postedQuestion.text = postedQuestion[indexPath.row]
    myCell.username.text = usernames[indexPath.row]

    myCell.sizeToFit()

    return myCell
 }

}
```

Error message:

> nil

I can see it is loading the data (from Parse) but then it just gives me that error message. It doesn't crash tho.

Thanks!

Comment: Your self.tableView.reloadData() should be outside the for loop.

Comment: Still the same error. Looks like it doesn't have anything to load. On my Parse, I can see the posts and usernames.

Comment: Is the operation in background thread?

Comment: I don't think so. Before it used to crash and give me a fatal error. Now it just says 'nil'.